# How to save an Excel sheet as PDF through MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab, pdf

I am using the following code:

```
hExcel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
hWorkbook = hExcel.Workbooks.Open(sprintf('%s','C:\test.xlsx'));
hWorksheet = hWorkbook.Sheets.Item(1);
hRange = hWorksheet.Range('A1:O10');
hRange.ExportAsFixedFormat('xlTypePDF','test_out.pdf');
```

The Excel ActiveX server allows me to do the usual stuff, but the last line doesn't do anything. Neither does it throw any error.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: As far as I can tell you just set a field so I am not surprised you don't get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `hWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat`, not `hRange.ExportAsFixedFormat`.

Also, you'll need to specify the full path to the output file as `C:\test_out.pdf`.